Angular / Typescript oauth2 login authorization - redirect url
We have an application typed in Angular for frontend and Scala for backend. We are implementing oauth2 authorization so people can login with Google account.
Backend created an endpoint which returns redirect url, so:
let's say endpoint
myapi/oauth2/url
returns a string with url to accounts.google.com where user is forwarded to
user accepts all agreements and is forwarded to site which is stored in the url mentioned earlier - in redirecturi param
that site is actually a http request, lets say:
myapi/oauth2/token
which return id, accessToken, refreshToken that I need to use
the problem is that i dont know how to catch that data, I can see it on the screen, but i have no idea what to do to use it
user is redirected to that endpoint like to a normal site
everything is done in backend, I just get the redirect url, and then need to assign the tokens returned also from backend
the endpoint
myapi/oauth2/token
also contains params generated in backend
for now lets say that no changes can be done to backend
my code would look like this:
authorizationService.getRedirectUrl().subscribe((url) => {
    window.location.href = url
}
)

I dont know how to even start with it, cant use token endpoint somewhere else because its generated through APItext

Thanks for sharing the question. Could you please add enough code snippets so we can understand your problem (better)?
